# Q: Is there an equivalent replacement to Pymongo `cursor.count()`? (3.7 -> 3.11)

Tags: python, pymongo, deprecated

I'm looking to upgrade from Pymongo 3.7 to 3.11 and ran into problems replacing the deprecated function `cursor.count()`. I need to know the number of documents returned from a query.

- `collection.count_documents({query})` is not the same as `cursor.count()`. First it's called on a collection, not a cursor. Second it the function parameters are different.

  -Speedwise this function is acceptable.

  -But in my current application layer there is no knowledge of the query. Hence, there is no knowing the argument to pass into `cursor.collection.count_documents()`
- `collection.estimated_document_count()` gives the *total* of documents in a collection, not the amount of documents in the returned query.
- `len(list(cursor))` is too slow for my needs.

Is there another way of counting the number of documents returned from a query?

Comment: What do you mean with "there is no knowledge of the query" -- surely you somehow know what to query?

Comment: Ok, there is knowledge of what to query :) But the actual _query_ is constructed in an adapter interface called `store` several layers below. For example,  from where the function call is made `my_cursor = store.read_from_db(some_id, arg1, arg2) `. And the returned `my_cursor` pointing to a subset of the collection. That subset- collection used to have its size as metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count_documents` is implemented via the driver constructing an aggregation pipeline and using the $count stage. There isn't a way to "attach" this count to a cursor, or to a find query.

You might need to rearchitect your application to pass the conditions to `count_documents`.